# Android Gradle error can only boot app up in chrome

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\olahe.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2011aaa867812614057a2ed04872494d\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\olahe.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\898ae8c55c64cdf4ba1778b1510f3f06\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is there in error message, your project's `minCompileSdk` is **30**, while a library (name is in error) is **31**. therefore either you should lower the library version. or increase your project's minCompileSdk.

mentioned libraries are:

- androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04
- androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04